# SSE Concurrent Connection Issue

Tags: server-sent-events

I want to implement an event based client server communication. Whenever some response comes in backend as part of some post operation(for eg:-payment process), need to post that backend data to frontend which is specific to each user. Each user should get his specific response in browser.

Our plan is to implement this using SSE, as this is one way communication.
Doing one POC with angularjs as frontend and springboot as backend. I am creating multiple event sources by creating separate instances for each user request like this:-
const eventSource = new EventSource(`http://localhost:8082/api/chat/sse/${clientId}`);

clientId is used to differentiate users.

Test scenario:-
User 1 performed his payment operation from his system. EventSource http://localhost:8082/api/chat/sse/1 gets registered for user1
User 2 performed his payment operation from his system simultaneously. EventSource http://localhost:8082/api/chat/sse/2 gets registered for user2
User 1 registered EventSource first and user 2 registered last.
When I try to open multiple eventsources for different users, now what is happening is only the last registered eventsource(here user 2) is going to open state and getting response back.
Rest of the users are not going to open state and from backend it's showing error like client aborted connection.

So here my query is:-

Is SSE not applicable for this scenario ?
Does SSE not support concurrent connections ?

A solution to the above problem

Comment: I suspect you are using the wrong tag.  [sse] is about Streaming SIMD extensions, which this does not appear to be about.  Consider retagging your question so that people can see it to answer it.

Comment: @RyanM: We (who follow the [sse] tag) get a handful of questions every week with this error, and edit accordingly.  This is the first one I've seen where there weren't any other tags, though.  What really grinds my gears is when people tag both [sse] and [server-sent-events], since they went to the trouble of finding what they thought could be redundant tags didn't bother to check the mouseovers to see if they really both applied. meta: [Stop users from tagging SSE and Server-Sent-Events in the same question, and warn for SSE + JS?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390150)